# How to run unittest.main() function from other module?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have an API that has unit tests written inside of it. The thing is that that API can't be run as 'stand-alone' script from terminal, it has to be run from a custom framework. In that API there is a function that basicly calls `unittest.main()` but test cases are not found if the function is ran from 'outside'. Is there a common solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: Did you already [look at the `unittest.main()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main)? The function explicitly supports such a scenario.

Comment: I haven't checked documentation but i get response that says `'Ran 0 tests in 0.000 seconds'`. But when i run it as a standalone script with if `'__name__ == '__main__'` then it finds test cases and runs them.

Comment: Then do check the documentation, that's what it is there for. It works when `__name__ == '__main__'` is true, but that's because it looks at `__main__` by default. You can tell it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `unittest.main()` to load the tests from a different module by passing the name of that module in as the first (or `module=`) argument.

For example, to use the *current* module name, use:

```
unittest.main(__name__)
```

You may want to [study the code that implements this functionality](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/unittest/main.py); `unittest.main` is an alias for the [`TestProgram` class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/unittest/main.py#L55-L273), which uses the standard `unittest` API to [discover, load and run tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#loading-and-running-tests). If you need more control it can be useful to just use the API directly.